# Read Special Characters in Socket Server

Tags: java, networking

I am creating Client/Server using Java Networking API. My client will send special unicode characters to Server before and after message. Before message it will send `\uc001B` and after message `\uc00C`. After message has been send successfully again client will send `\r` to server. Server can identify by receiving of this that the message sending is done. But my problem here is how can I check in the server whether the message from client has `\r`.

```
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream( clientSocket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    clientSocket.getInputStream()));
outToServer.writeBytes("\uc001B");
outToServer.flush();
outToServer.writeBytes(message.toString());
outToServer.writeBytes("\uc001C");
outToServer.flush();
outToServer.writeBytes("\r");
outToServer.flush();
```

And here is my server Code to read messages from the client

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(m_clientSocket.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(   m_clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
String receivingMessage = "";
while (m_bRunThread) {
   String clientCommand = in.readLine().toString();
   receivingMessage += clientCommand;
   System.out.println("Client Says :" + clientCommand);
   if (in.equals("\r")) {
      System.out.print("Message Receiving from Client Done : "+ m_clientID);
      m_bRunThread = false;
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling readLine().toString()? It already is a String, unless it is null, which you aren't checking for. This code will NPE at end of stream.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `readLine().` It removes the newline, whatever it was: it understands all of them. Ergo you cannot possibly tell what the newline character was. Also you cannot possibly care. Every line you read was terminated by a newline character. But you are on fairly dangerous ground using STX and ETX in association with a Reader. You seem to have a protocol definition problem: you are sending STX/ETX and *also* expecting newlines. Why?

Comment: Hi Thanks, I got it now I am using read() and can check for the Carriage Return value.

Comment: @Ramo I still don't know why you need it, or why you're even sending it. You already have STX/ETX, that's enough. You don't need the belt and the braces.

Comment: Hi Actually its HL7 messaging standard, whenever there is a request from client, server should check whether the full message from client received. To check that, from the client needs to pass any special character after the message. So to mt HL7 standards we are using Carriage Return as the indicator for end of message.

Comment: @Pramo Does HL7 really specify *both* STX/ETX and another message terminator? Hard to believe.

Comment: Yes it is! they had given certain rules to follow to pass the message from client to server